# Can I ensure interoperability over TCP in a WCF service?

Tags: .net, wcf, tcp

I'm creating a service and I have two strict requirements: the service has to communicate over TCP and; the service must be interoperable.

The more I read about TCP transport with WCF it seems like it's not guaranteed to be interoperable. I thought writing a Custom Binding could be the way around it but TcpTransportBindingElement also seems to be .NET specific :

> The WCF TCP transport is optimized for the scenario where both ends of
>   the communication are using WCF.

Is writing the service in WCF compatible with these requirements? Is there any way to make WCF use standard (non-proprietary) TCP?

Comment: "interoperable" with what? To be able to answer if it "meets your requirements" we need to know what your requirements state you have to interop with. Also, did you know that ***ALL*** of the built in bindings use TCP, it is just the message protocol over TCP that changes when you switch types.

Comment: I suppose by "interoperability" I mean that we can't restrict what technology the clients are using, be it .NET or Java or something else. The requirement could then be more clearly stated as "accept a message over TCP from a client using any technology".

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to be "interoperable" with other .NET application any of the bindings will be fine for compatibility. If you are trying to be "interoperable" with other platforms like Java which can support SOAP messages but not necessarily with Microsoft's proprietary message protocol used in `NetTcpBinding` then you will likely want to go with [any of the protocols](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731092(v=vs.110).aspx) that contain "Http" in their name.

As for TCP, all of the system provided bindings use TCP for their transport, all the difference between them is how the message protocol works on top of TCP.

Comment: OK that's interesting thanks. A fuller explanation of what we're doing is that our server and the unknown clients are all working to a 3rd party standard that says "everyone has to communicate over TCP and pass these kinds of messages to one another". We used to do it at sockets layer and are now thinking of doing it via WCF. So I guess I just want to ensure that a WCF service can do TCP without the proprietary message encoding, I should be able to create a custom binding to deal with the messages if the TCP is OK.

Comment: You are correct "and pass these kinds of messages to one another" will be the hard part, you will need to write your own [Custom Encoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735115(v=vs.110).aspx) to follow the message protocol. You may be able to get away with the TCP transport built in to .NET under the encoder, but if it does not work you could always [write a custom one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2006/05/08/592110.aspx). but then you would just be reimplementing your sockets layer program with a wcf layer on top of it, which would likely be more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: @bucktronic with the more details you provided, I would suggest you drop trying to use WCF and just make a class that wraps your sockets implementation with easy to use calls that represents the various messages you want to send. I think it will be less headaches and will be a lot easier to do.